# How is it decided how much of virtual address space is mapped in page table?

Tags: arm, mmu

I have read that Arm V7 ISA gives 4gig of virtual address space for a program. If i take a program in which all the code come within 4kilobyte, my question is whether entire 4gig of space is mapped in page table? I we take short descriptor format for building page tables and use a 4k granularity, it will take a lot of space in the ram to hold the page table. So i think the whole 4GB of space for a single process is not mapped but only a part of it is mapped. Is this correct? If it is correct then how is it decided how much of the VA is mapped in the tables?

Comment: This is either specific to an OS (so state which operating system you are asking about), or if you implement it yourself on top of bare metal, it is up to you.

Comment: @nos If i take linux os, and i say that i have a store instruction which stores a value at 0x10000000, will the os figure out that address 0x10000000 will be written to and so it has to be mapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ARM, the page tables have multiple levels. The first level has 4096 entries as far as I can remember - each describing a 1MB section.

From there you can break up the 1MB section into 4KB sizes (or larger - I can't remember what other sizes) by giving a pointer to a second level page table containing 256 entries describing 4KB sections.

The top level 1MB sections all have to be mapped - whether they have to be mapped *to something* is decided to the OS. If an area isn't needed, some OS's will just fill in the entry to page fault.

You certainly don't want to divide up the entire memory space into 4KB chunks - the page table size would be enormous.

Comment: How dose os figure out how much of VA will be used? If I have a store instruction that writes to a high value say 0x10000000, dose os figure out that it has to map 0x10000000 in tables? Is using such a store instruction legal?

Comment: Every OS will manage the virtual address space differently. The OS doesn't 'figure out' anything. Either the space has been mapped by the kernel prior to access (in which case, the address is translated by the MMU and the kernel plays no further part in its access) or the kernel marks it as invalid and when it is accessed, the kernel is given control again where it maps it on-the-fly (this is known as copy-on-write).